# Special characters seem to swap HTML letter order

Tags: html, encoding, character-encoding

Why is the red part AFTER the `:...` in the following text and not before?

This was rendered with Windows 7, Firefox 47:

[image]

```html
<p><b style="color: red;">לה</b>: להz</p>
```

Comment: Have you tried other snippets, like `<p><b style="color: red;">לה</b>: להלהלהלהלהלהלהz</p>` and `<p><b style="color: red;">לה</b>: z</p>` ?

Comment: If I slightly modify the snippet, the problem is solved. I don't know why. But as it is, it's very strange.

Comment: Weird behavior, but I'm guessing it's because you're using language that is traditionally RTL-based?

Comment: I don't know at all. I don't know these characters. I was just trying if the application I'm writing is all-UTF8-weird-characters-proof.

Comment: I think you are just very unlucky. Somehow the text directionality is being incorrectly processed by the DOM and it is taking the first לה it sees (RTL) and applying the style. And you got unlucky since you had multiple לה occurrences. Perhaps use CSS text-direction to trick it. Or shove a zero-width-joiner in there! Have fun hacking!

Comment: Maybe @RayToal. How to prevent this to happen while still keeping user input allowed in wide UTF8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its longer and there is possibly a better way, but this seems to work:

`<p style="display: inline-block;"><b style="color: red;">לה</b></p><p style="display: inline-block;">: להz</p>`

Comment: @Basj I believe that it is because the first symbol is written as a right-to-left character while the other four are written as left-to-right.

Comment: Carter's answer is appropriate. You're not making your user's type the two strings and the colon, right? They type text and you show the name to the left of the colon and the message to the right, correct? If so, then your app has control over both pieces as separate pieces of content. You _should_ IMHO, slap some CSS over it to present it the way you want That is what CSS is for. Maybe you have other  requirements, but I would suspect in a chat app you'd take Carter's approach.

Comment: It is possible as stated here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_direction.asp to inherit the text direction from the parent elements if your code would allow this.